# XSL Transform XML

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have some xml in the following format:

```
<fileExport>
  <rows>
    <row id="0">
      <columns>
        <column id="0">
          <name>Date Time</name>
          <value>2010-10-2 23:00:00 GMT</value>
        </column>
        <column id="1">
          <name>Primary</name>
          <value>100.1</value> 
        </column>
        <column id="2">
          <name>Manual</name>
          <value>20.5</value>
        </column>
        ...
      </columns>
    </row>
    <row id="1">
      <columns>
        <column id="0">
          <name>Date Time</name>
          <value>2010-10-3 00:00:00 GMT</value>
        </column>
        <column id="1">
          <name>Primary</name>
          <value>110.5</value> 
        </column>
        ...
        <column id="2">
          <name>Manual</name>
          <value>23.1</value>
        </column>
      </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>  
</fileExport>
```

Now the idea is to transform this to CSV text.  Everything seems to be working fine - but I have 32 columns for each row in the above.  To transform this to CSV, I am using the following XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//rows/row">
      <!-- Now add a new row for each column -->

      <!-- first row in file for this row in table -->
      <xsl:text>A</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="columns/column[name='Date Time']/value"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="columns/column[name='Primary']/value"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>P</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

      <!-- second row in file for this row in table -->
      <xsl:text>A</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="columns/column[name='Date Time']/value"/>  
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="columns/column[name='Manual']/value"/>
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>M</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>

      ... now repeat for the next 30 columns ...

      <!-- next row in table-->
    </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:text>&lt;EOF&gt;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now that gives us the output:

```
A,2010-10-2 23:00:00 GMT,100.1,P
A,2010-10-2 23:00:00 GMT,20.5,M
A,2010-10-3 00:00:00 GMT,110.5,P
A,2010-10-3 00:00:00 GMT,23.1,M
<EOF>
```

Question is, having 32 or so columns in the XML is it possible to shorten the XSL required to achieve the same results?

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Andez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this help ?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/fileExport">
     <xsl:for-each select="rows/row">
         <xsl:variable name="date" select="columns/column[name='Date Time']/value"/>
         <xsl:for-each select="columns/column">
             <xsl:if test="name!='Date Time'">
                <xsl:text>A</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                 <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="name='Primary'">P</xsl:when>
                     <xsl:when test="name='Manual'">M</xsl:when>
                     ....
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>&lt;EOF&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: what is the logic with the last field data the primary assumption is the first letter or the name, but I was worried of more bizarre variants

Answer (score 4):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="row">
        <xsl:text>A</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="value">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(',',.)"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="column[name='Primary' or name='Manual']">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(',',substring(name,1,1))"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="row[position() mod 2]/*/column[name='Manual']|
                         row[position() mod 2 = 0]/*/column[name='Primary']|
                         text()" priority="1"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
A,2010-10-2 23:00:00 GMT,100.1,P
A,2010-10-3 00:00:00 GMT,23.1,M
```

Comment: +1 nice implementation, use of template match patterns for conditional processing.

Comment: Looks better than what I've come up with.  Think I'll check out templates and do a little more reading first.

Comment: @Andez: In order to understand this you also have to know the [built-in rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#built-in-rule). The meaning of all this is: *`row` to 'A'-childs result-NL; `value` to ','-string value; 'Primary' or 'Manual' column to childs result-','-first letter of `name`; don't process a 'Manual' column for odd `row`, nor 'Primary' column for even `row`, nor text nodes*.